# Replace part of a string in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, replace

I recently moved my mp3 library to my home folder, and this caused banshee to forget my file data (such as rating, ect).  If I can update the file path in banshee's sqlite table, I can get restore my user-entered file data.

`sqlite` stores path data in a `Uri` field of the `CoreTracks` table.

Example:

```
Uri
file:///storage/Music/mp3/Genre/Artist/Album/Track.mp3
```

I'd like to change all instances to

```
file:///home/user/Music/mp3/Genre/Artist/Album/Track.mp3
```

Is there a safe way of changing just the first 15 characters of data contained in the Uri field?

Comment: This is a database question?!?   I personally do not care where it lives, but sqlite is a database, and the question deals with UPDATing fields in that database.

Answer (score 0):

Create the database backup. Then use the sqlite.exe command line shell. open your database like this:

```
sqlite rating.sqlite
> UPDATE CoreTracks SET Uri = 'file:///home/user' + substr(Uri, 17);
>
```

At the end press Ctrl-D to finish the sqlite console. I think I counted the characters correctly. Please double check if value 17 needs to be changed to something else